# Mysql PHP do not show duplicate id

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I want remove duplicate usernames from this query:

```
SELECT
    transactions.id,
    transactions.user_id,
    transactions.dikaioma,
    transactions.`in`,
    users.`name` AS username,
    users.score,
    users.startDikaioma,
    transactions.`out`,
    games.`name`,
    banks.bank_id,
    banks.sxolio
FROM
    transactions
INNER JOIN 
    users ON transactions.user_id = users.id
INNER JOIN 
    games ON users.curgame = games.id
INNER JOIN 
    posta ON users.posto_id = posta.posto_id
INNER JOIN 
    banks ON posta.posto_bank_id = banks.bank_id
WHERE
    transactions.`in` NOT BETWEEN 0 AND 1
ORDER BY
    transactions.id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Can somebody help me how to 
do not show duplicate id from users i try

```
GROUP BY users.id HAVING count(users.id) > 1)
```

but not work .. error

Comment: Are you searching for `distinct` maybe? See [this article](http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-distinct-sql-tutorial/)

Comment: You could use `GROUP BY users.id HAVING count(users.id) >= 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `DISTINCT` after `SELECT`. That should omit any duplicates.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-distinct-keyword.htm

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the DISTINCT function on the column that you would like to not have duplicates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
transactions.id,
transactions.user_id,
transactions.dikaioma,
transactions.`in`,
users.`name` AS username,
users.score,
users.startDikaioma,
transactions.`out`,
games.`name`,
banks.bank_id,
banks.sxolio
FROM
transactions
INNER JOIN users ON transactions.user_id = users.id
INNER JOIN games ON users.curgame = games.id
INNER JOIN posta ON users.posto_id = posta.posto_id
INNER JOIN banks ON posta.posto_bank_id = banks.bank_id
WHERE
transactions.`in` NOT BETWEEN 0 AND 1
ORDER BY
transactions.id DESC
LIMIT 10
```